# PowerBI Desktop: intermittent ORA-03113 errors

Tags: oracle, odbc, powerbi, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am connecting to oracle 12 in Oracle cloud, from PowerBI Desktop windows server 2016. 
Oracle client is installed and TNS file configured.
Oracle is hosted by a vendor so my only access is to directly query the database.

In powerBI, when using an oracle connection, i get ORA-03113 errors about 50% of the time when refreshing data. There is no discernible pattern to the appearance of the error.

If i connect via a System ODBC connection set up in windows, I dont get any issues or errors, although the data load is a bit slower.

I would appreciate ideas on what may be causing this issue or what to check to help get more information.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid your issue needs some deeper analysis as ORA-03113 might have various reasons, but typically it means that the 'oracle' executable has terminated unexpectedly once there was an existing connection. You should try to isolate the SQL command that is executing when the error occurs. It can be done either by checking the trace files on the server or by using SQL*Net trace if you don't have access to the server. If a statement can be isolated which consistently raises the ORA-3113 error, then it can be further analysed (like execution plan, triggers, etc), or maybe the best to raise an SR so Oracle Support can work on the issue. If you have access to Oracle Support you can find more information about ORA-03113 troubleshooting in MOS Doc ID 1506805.1. Let me know if I can help you any further.